# How to convert a specific amount of characters to uppercase or lowercase and count how many uppercase and lowercase letters a word has

Tags: c++, string, ctypes, uppercase, lowercase

The function that is intended to convert a word to uppercase or lowercase converts the entire word to uppercase or lowercase. What I want to do is convert a specific amount of characters in the string to uppercase or lowercase. Take the word string for example. If the user only wants to convert the letter S in the word string to uppercase, then the output should be: String. Also, this function takes into account if the word that they want to convert is already in uppercase or lowercase.

Example: User enters the word STRING. wants to convert the word to STRing.
output:STRING

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>  
#include <cctype> 
using namespace std;

//Function Prototype
int CountVowels(string, int &);
void ShowMenu(string &, char &);
void convertword(string &);

int main()
{
//Variables
string word;
char choice = '0';
int vowels = 0;

do
{
//Call Functions
ShowMenu(word, choice);

switch(choice)
{
case '1':
    cout << CountVowels(word, vowels);
    cout << endl << endl;
    break;

case '2':
    convertword(word);
    cout << endl << endl;
    break;
}

}while(choice != '5');

return 0;
}

void ShowMenu(string& word, char& choice)
{
cout <<"\t\tMENU\t\t" << endl
     <<"===========================================" << endl;
cout <<"1. Find the number of Vowels in a word" << endl
     <<"2. Convert to uppercase or lowercase " << endl
     <<"3. Count the number of uppercase letters  " << endl
     <<"4. Count the number of lowercase letters" << endl
     <<"5. Quit"
     <<"\n===========================================" << endl;
//Get menu choice and get word from user.
cout << endl;
cout <<"Enter a choice: ";
cin >> choice;

while((!isdigit(choice)) || (choice > '5'))
{
    cerr << "\nOut of range or invalid input. ";
    cin >> choice;
}

cin.ignore();

cout << endl;

cout << "Enter a word: ";
getline(cin, word, '\n');


}

int CountVowels(string word, int& vowelCount)
{
vowelCount = 0;

int numLetters = word.length();  //get the number of letters in a word

for (int i = 0; i < numLetters; i++)
{
    char letter = word[i];  //get the ith letter in the word

    if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'e' ||
        letter == 'i' || letter == 'o' ||
        letter == 'u' || letter == 'y' )
    {
        vowelCount++;
    }


}

cout << "\nThe number of vowels in this word is : ";

return vowelCount;
}

void convertword(string &word)
{
bool same = false;
char response;

cout << "\nWould you like to convert this word to uppercase or lowercase. " << endl;
cout << "\nType U for uppercase and l for lowercase. ";
cin >> response;

while(response != 'U' && response != 'l')
{
    cerr  << "\nInvalid input. ";
    cin >> response;
}

for(unsigned int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
{
    if((response == 'U' && word[i]==toupper(word[i])))
    {
        same = true;
    }
    else if(response == 'U')
    {
        word[i]=toupper(word[i]);
    }
    else if((response == 'l' && word[i]==tolower(word[i])))
    {
        same = true;
    }
    else if(response == 'l')
    {
        word[i]=tolower(word[i]);
    }
}

cout << endl;

if(same)
{
    cout << "\nBased on your response, this word has already been converted. ";
}
else
    cout << "\nyour newly converted or unconverted word is : " << word;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What do you want expect for input and output?  What are you currently getting?

Comment: I already gave you an example in the description but here it is again. If the user inputs the word string, and the user only wants to convert the letter S in the word string to uppercase, the output should be String. The output I get is STRING.

Comment: Don't do word[i]=toupper(word[i]); in a loop.  Rather just do word[0] = toupper( word[0] ); outside of the loop.

Comment: Yes I was thinking of doing that but what if the user only wants STRIng if they input string or if they input STRING and only want String.

Comment: Keep in mind that this function also has to watch out for words that are the same. Meaning, if they input string, and they want to convert to lowercase, then the output should be: No need to convert.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Capitalizes the first letter and all others are lower case.
size_t n = the number of characters you want.
if( !word.empty() )
{
    if( n > word.size() )
        n = word.size();
    for( size_t i = 0; i < word.size(); ++i )
        word[i] = toupper( word[i] );
    for( size_t i = n; i < word.size(); ++i )
        word[i] = tolower( word[i] );
}
```

Comment: Yes, like I was thinking of doing that. The thing is what if the user wants to capitalize the word string to STRing or even STRing to string. Should I ask the user how many letters does he want to convert and then use that input in a for loop?

Comment: Like I said, your description is very bad of what you want.

Comment: Can you please explain why?